# az pipelines build queue - script fails if I use Variables parameter

Tags: azure, azure-cli, command-line-tool

I am working on a script to update two pipeline variables - patchname and version no and using the below script fails and throws an error.

az pipelines build queue  --org $org --project $project --definition-name $pipelane --variables VersionNo=$VersionNo PatchName=$patchname

Error:

az : ERROR: Could not queue the build because there were validation errors or warnings.
At C:\Users\MEHIYA\source\Powershell\Masterscripts\ALM-Scripts - Mustaque\QueryBuilder.ps1:23 char:1

- az pipelines build queue  --org $org --project $project --definition- ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ERROR: Could no...rs or warnings.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
  ```

in MS Docs, it says --variables should be "Space separated "name=value" pairs for the variables you would like to set."

Few blogs also have defined the pipeline variables as above but it is not working for me.

I tried various ways to define the variables but nothing worked.

1. --variables VersionNo=$VersionNo PatchName=$patchname
2. --variables VersionNo=$VersionNo (tried with giving only one variable, but that doesnt also work)
3. --variables "VersionNo=$VersionNo" "PatchName=$patchname" (putting each variable in quotes)
4. --variables "VersionNo=$VersionNo PatchName=$patchname" (putting the whole set of variables in quotes).

can you please help me how this should be defined here?

Note:  As a work around, I am able to update the parameters using the az pipelines variable update --name PatchName --value=$patchname, but it updates the pipeline variables but shows a warning like below.

az : WARNING: Command group 'pipelines variable' is in preview and under development. Reference and support levels: https://aka.ms/CLI_refstatus
At line:1 char:1

- az pipelines variable update --name PatchName --value="MustaqueTest_P ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (WARNING: Comman...s/CLI_refstatus:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
  ```

Is this advised to use the work around, but I prefer to pass it in the az pipelines build queue command instead of another few more lines of codes.

Comment: As per another CLI response from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68621741/not-able-to-link-multiple-workitems-to-a-pull-request-when-i-create-using-az-rep, I updated the command as below --variables @('SolutionName=$PatchName', 'SolutionVersion=$PatchVersion') and tried, but it did not work in this case.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your issue despite trying multiple versions. Can you first try running the command from the terminal with the `--debug` parameter and see if the parameters are expected?