# Not able to link multiple workitems to a Pull request when I create using az repos pr create

Tags: command-line-interface, azure-powershell, azure-cli, azure-automation, azure-cli2

I am creating a script to do a Pull request using the below Azure CLI script.

az repos pr create --description $PR_Description --merge-commit-message $PR_WorkItemNo --org $orgname --source-branch $PatchName --target-branch "main" --title $PR_Title --project $projectname --repository $PR_repository --work-items $linkedworkitemno

Assigning a single work item (eg "72076") to this variable $linkedworkitemno - works fine and associates the single work item to the PR.

But when I add two work items with space (eg "72076 72126") - as explained in MS Docs (- --work-items - IDs of the work items to link to the new pull request. Space separated https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/repos/pr?view=azure-cli-latest#az_repos_pr_create), it is not linking both items to the PR and only associates the FIRST work item.

can you please help me with this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please to it as follows:

```
$linkedworkitemno = @('72076', '72126')
```

and then:

```
--work-items $linkedworkitemno
```

Comment: It worked with this option. THank you, but @krzysztof - what does the MS documentation refers to when they say "Space separated"..